# Put some image pattern on letters with php

Tags: php

I am trying to write some text on another image but I want some pattern on letters. Writing on image is easy. But I have no idea how to put that pattern :(. This is an example I made in Photoshop http://goo.gl/EYXI5c

I have only GD on server. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Do You imagemagick installed on the server, then i think you can do that.

Comment: do you have different patterns (having different pattern in char 'a' for each occurrence in word) or only one pattern (having single pattern in char 'a' for each occurrence in word)?

Comment: Patterns and text are custom. User has to type some text and than choose a pattern.

Comment: ok, I have one solution for that... Create font pattern as an image and use it.

Comment: hmm, that can be nice solution :)

Comment: It is nice solution, but you have to create 62 (If there isn't any special characters) same pattern images of characters.. and you have to manage font size with image size as well..!!

Comment: Yes I know :(. I have 30 letters in my language :D, so it is only 60 small images :)

Comment: have you counted numbers and special characters like : ; ' " # @ $ % ? ! , . All The Best!! :) Yes,You can do it..

Comment: BTW, you have some innovative idea.. I'll try by myself as well, If I get another nicer way!!